# object method not modifying other property in the same object

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods

I'm trying to set up a function that sets up a countdown and then triggers another function/event when it reaches 0. I'm linking it with HTML to set up various button selectors to be able to increment the countdown by 1, 2, or 3 ticks.

The problem is that I can get the page to display the min/max timer with no issue, by adding `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = myTime.curTime + "/" + myTime.maxTime`
at the top of the HTML document, but I can't get it to update the curTime, and curTime never seems to update inside the object either. Is this just an issue with how I've structured it? Or should I be approaching this a different way?

Here is what I have so far:
(link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4Lu3n43/)

```
//set the initial value of timer
var timerDown = 0

//set up the countdown constructor
function Countdown(name, baseTime, inc) {
    this.name = name;
    this.timer = baseTime;
    this.increment = inc;
    this.maxTime = maxTime();
    this.curTime = curTime();
}

//set up the functions for the Countdown prototype
Countdown.prototype = {
    maxTime: function() {
        return (this.timer + this.increment) * 2;
    },
    curTime: function() {
        return maxTime - timerDown;
    }
}

//set up the function to now de-increment the timer to 0
function deIncrement(numInc) {
    timerDown += numInc;
    if (myTime.curTime <= 0 ) {
    alert("You've run out of time!");
    } else { 
        updateTimer();
    }
}

//set up the countdown object
var myTime = new Countdown("Timer", 10, 2);

//set up the function to update the div on the HTML page
function updateTimer() { 
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer") 
    timer.innerHTML = myTime.curTime + "/" + myTime.maxTime;
}

window.onload = updateTimer();
```

And the HTML portion of it:

```
<div id="timer">Time will go here</div>
<input type="button" id="inc1" onclick="deIncrement(1); return false" value="Coundown by 1">
<input type="button" id="inc2" onclick="deIncrement(2); return false" value="Coundown by 2">
<input type="button" id="inc3" onclick="deIncrement(3); return false" value="Coundown by 3">
<input type="button" id="inc4" onclick="deIncrement(4); return false" value="Coundown by 4">
```

Comment: If you wanted to reference the function that's not the correct way to do it. Also, you cannot hold a function inside a variable that has the same name of the function.

Comment: @briosheje
I have had 0 issues using `this.value = value();` with numerous other objects and methods, what would be the correct way to reference it? Your answer was not even the least bit helpful.

Comment: as long as value() is a global function this can be done, but you cannot extend the base object by giving it a function that has the same name as a property, check your javascript console to see such. http://prntscr.com/6wk71d and http://prntscr.com/6wk7o7 taken directly from your fiddle. Also, for the sake of not looking like the bad boy, I didn't vote down.

Comment: That's really strange, I wonder why it works on other times that I've done it that exact way previously. Is it because in other cases I'm using the function only with values obtained in the object itself? but when access a global variable it needs to have a different name?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no language where you can have a object with two properties that have the same name but different types. They propably would, in fact, overwrite. In your case, if the functions were GLOBAL that would have been fine, but this is not the case :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code...

First you need to set a function to `window.onload`, not call the function and put the result in `window.onload`.

Next as briosheje said, you cannot have `maxTime` as a property and a function of the same object (even if you're using the prototype). Just use the function to get the latest value every time.

Be sure to use `this.myFunction()` (as opposed to `myFunction()`) to use another function/object from the object you're currently in.

Finally, your jsFiddle needed to run directly in the `<head>` element in order to use `window.onload` and named functions that are accessed from inline HTML attributes (ie. `deIncrement`). This was a configuration option set on the left-top of the page.

See the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4Lu3n43/2/